# What's the purpose in sending a malicious .js file over email?

Tags: windows, javascript, trojan

I was told that a suspicious looking email appeared in one's email and upon clicking the link it downloaded a ZIP archive with only a single `.js` file in it.

The code was obfuscated, but I managed to work out what it actually does.
Here's a [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/pexozajewu.js) link to it.

It looks like this script is trying to use an `ActiveXObject` which is only available on Internet Explorer, as far as I'm concerned.

So my question is - *what was the attacker expecting?* I don't think it's common to have a standalone JS shell installed, so I'm guessing that an average user wouldn't even be able to execute it.

P.S. When I accessed the URL in the code through a browser, it displayed a plain cyanish page with some text in it. However, when I downloaded what that URL was pointing to, it turned out to be an executable of some sort (judging by the `This program cannot be run in DOS mode` in the beginning). If some bright-minded person could shed some light on what that executable could do, I'd be glad to hear it :)

Comment: unfortunately, we can't do code reviews for random malware code

Comment: *"I don't think it's common to have a standalone JS shell installed..."* - it is actually common. It's called windows scripting host. And js inside zip (or some other archive formats like 7z) is probably 80% of the malware I get in mails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is malware distributed within zip files?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118804/), [How does malware downloaded by JavaScript get executed, and why would you distribute malware in a .js file?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130206) and [many more similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=zip+javascript+site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com).

Comment: windows runs "js" files. not the same js files as browsers, but js files nonetheless